# Release a file lock that send-mailmessage leaves on error

Tags: email, powershell, powershell-2.0, filelock

I'm using the Send-MailMessage cmdlet to send a copy of a log file. However, I'd like to add a line to the log file with the status of the Send.

Code:

```
$To = "toaddress@email.com"
$Subject = "Test Email Attachment"
$From = "fromaddress@email.com"
$Body = "Please find log file attached"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.server.com"
$LogFile = "Testlog.log"

Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "Trying to email log..."
Try
    {
        send-mailmessage -to $To -subject $Subject -From $From -body $Body -smtpserver $SMTPServer -attachments $LogFile -ErrorAction Stop
        Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "Successfully emailed log to: $To"
    }
Catch [system.exception]
    {
        Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "Error emailing log to: $To"
    }
Finally {}
```

Error:

```
PS E:\> . .\TestMail.ps1
Add-Content : The process cannot access the file 'E:\Testlog.log' because it is being used by another process.
At E:\TestMail.ps1:16 char:14
+         Add-Content <<<<  -Path $LogFile -Value "Error emailing log to: $To"
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (E:\Testlog.log:String) [Add-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

This works fine if the email succeeds, but if it fails (say the smtp server is unavailable), and erroraction is set to "Stop", then the file lock on the log file doesn't get released. If erroraction is *not* set to "Stop", then the log file gets released, but the Catch block doesn't get triggered.

I found a reference to the "dispose" method if you're rolling your own mail function, but I'm not sure how it could be used with the Send-MailMessage cmdlet: http://petermorrissey.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/sending-email-messages-with-powershell.html

Is there a command I should run to release the lock, or is this a bug, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Just found this bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/785417/out-file-cannot-access-logfile-references-in-attachments-of-failed-send-mailmessage-call

Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/785417/out-file-cannot-access-logfile-references-in-attachments-of-failed-send-mailmessage-call

Email a copy of the file or create your own email function using PowerShell 1 methods (One example: [how to send an email with attachement using powershell v1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652359/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachement-using-powershell-v1))